# C++ Dll Injection

Tags: c++, dll, process, code-injection

I would really appreciate your help in this.

I have been trying to get a Dll injected into a remote process and do a few changes inside it, the problem I'm encountering right now is i don't know how to get this going.

So first, here is my piece of code that I have developed so far:

dllmain.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                       DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                       LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ )
{
switch (reason)
    {
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
           MessageBox (0, "From DLL\n", "Process Attach", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;

      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
           MessageBox (0, "From DLL\n", "Process Detach", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
           MessageBox (0, "From DLL\n", "Thread Attach", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
           MessageBox (0, "From DLL\n", "Thread Detach", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;
    }  

    return TRUE;
}
```

It simply displays a message box depending on the conditions it meets.
Now what I would like my Dll to do is, after being injected into the remote process, I would like it to write a memory location and change it's value.

Data type: Unsigned Short Int
Memory location: 0041D090

I hope everything is clear,
Thank you for your patience, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to write a DLL to change another process's memory at a fixed address.  You can use `WriteProcessMemory()`.

However...  The way to inject a DLL into another process is the following...

1. Use [`VirtualAllocEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366890(VS.85).aspx) to allocate the length of the file path to the DLL inside the target process's memory...  This is like remotely doing a `malloc`.
2. Use `WriteProcessMemory()` to copy the file path to the DLL into what was returned from the previous step.  This is like remotely doing a `strcpy`.
3. Use `CreateRemoteThread()`.  You can point it at `LoadLibrary()` as the entry point and the file path from steps 1 and 2 as the argument.  That's a bit hacky, to be honest, but if you are injecting a DLL you're already being quite hacky.  Another technique would be to use steps 1 & 2 to load some machine code into the remote proceess and point it at that.

Keep in mind that this technique is a great way to destabilize the target process.  In particular, this isn't something I'd do in a product that ends up getting shipped to others.

Comment: I see, that would be the steps to follow for creating the injector to inject the Dll itself, if I get you right. But, what should I do with my Dll after injecting it into the remote process and creating a thread for it? WriteProcessMemory()?

Comment: Well, at that point, in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH of your DLLMain you could just do *((DWORD *)0x0041D090) = SomeValue; My earlier point though was that you don't need a DLL injected to do this, you can just WriteProcessMemory() from a different process.

Comment: Hmm, I think that is what I needed. Anyway, the point for me in injecting a Dll instead of simply using WriteProcessMemory() from another process, is that I would like to still be able to modify the values in the remote process after my process that injects the Dll is closed. Anyway, I'll go try that out and see if I get any errors. Thank you.